# Sugar ORM - how to get attribute of the returned object by listAll method?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sugarorm

I have the following snippet:

```
public void readUsersSugarDB() {
        // SUGAR DB TEST
        try {
            List<User> users = User.listAll(User.class);

            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                User userObject = users.get(i);
                Logger.i(userObject.getUserName());
                Logger.i(userObject.toString());
            }
            //Integer userCount = User.getTableName(User.class);
            Logger.i("Users list", users);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("Sugar_db_exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I would like to access directly to the object properties (name, surname) but i cannnot. I must to create getter Method on the model to get name and surname.

Is possible to access object attributes without having to create getters on the model? Anf if yes, how can i do it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

**Model class:**

```
public class User extends SugarRecord<User>{
    String name;
    String surname;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: try declaring the fields as public.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default modifier,declare the fields as public then you'll be able to access it in such way:

```
user.name;
user.surname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt call of a right way the attributes in your method, you have to change `userObject.getUserName()` for `userObject.name.toString()`

### The code will be like this:

```
public void readUsersSugarDB() {
        // SUGAR DB TEST
        try {
            List<User> users = User.listAll(User.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                User userObject = users.get(i);
                Logger.i(userObject.name.toString());
                Logger.i(userObject.toString());
            }
            //Integer userCount = User.getTableName(User.class);
            Logger.i("Users list", users);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("Sugar_db_exception", e.getMessage());
        }
  }
```